# Python. Как передать в map() булевую переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x, map

```
def get_string(movie_data_list, ratings_list, full_bool=True):
    # some code

full_bool = True
string_list = map(get_string, movie_data_list, ratings_list, full_bool)
    # full_bool - boolean and not iterable
    # get_string - main func using by map()
```

Как можно реализовать данную концепцию? Проблема в том, что `map()` принимает первым аргументом фунцию, аргументами которой являются следующие **итерируемые** аргументы, идущие после неё, т.е. `movie_data_list`, `ratings_list` - **итерируемые**, а `full_bool` - **булевая переменная**. В итоге: `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`. Единственное, что мне нужно, это передать флажок `True` or `False`. Вариант со списком одинаковых bool значений очевиден, но, думаю, не самое лучшее решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, Вам надо написать так:

```
string_list = map(lambda x, y: get_string(x, y, True), movie_data_list, ratings_list)
```

Таким образом, лишь 2 аргумента `map` берёт из переданных параметров, третий - всегда `True`

Answer (score 2):

Можно передать [частично применённую](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) функцию

```
from functools import partial

string_list = map(partial(get_string, full_bool=True), movie_data_list, ratings_list)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial